# Insert an array into a grouped array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a grouped array

```
{
Blues: [{title:"Blues", color:"red" },{title:"Blues",color:"white" },{title:"Blues",color:"white" }],
Jazz:  [{title:"Jazz", color:"orange"},{title:"Jazz",color:"pink"}]
Rock:  [{title:"Rock", color:"yellow"},{title:"Rock", color:"yellow"}]
}
```

Then I will have another array `{title:"Rock", color:"gold"}` is there a way that i can put that array into the specific grouped array? and if it dont have a key for the grouping it will create a new group like `{title:"Metal", color:"gold"}`

```
{
Blues: [{title:"Blues", color:"red" },{title:"Blues",color:"white" },{title:"Blues",color:"white" }],
Jazz:  [{title:"Jazz", color:"orange"},{title:"Jazz",color:"pink"}],
Rock:  [{title:"Rock", color:"yellow"},{title:"Rock", color:"yellow"}],
Metal: [{title:"Metal", color:"gold"}]

}
```

Comment: Get the `title` property of the new item, then check if a key with the same name exists in the big group (hint: use the `in` operator). If it exists just add it to the list if not just do `group[title] = [newItem]`

Comment: Please post the actual JavaScript code you tried to use to meet your objective.p

Comment: what ive done so far was i get the raw array then concat the new object then do a setState again to make group `var joined = this.state.classDetailFromApi.concat(tobeAddlocalStore);
            this.setState({ classDetailFromApi: joined ,classDetailFromApis: _.groupBy(this.state.classDetailFromApi, 'title')  })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an array of that you're trying to insert, you have an object that you want to insert to an existing array or create an array with the object if the key doesn't exist.

```
function addOrCreate(value)
{

    // Get the keys that the object contains (e.g. "Blues", "Jazz" etc)
    var keys = Object.keys(arr);

    // Check if the title is in the keys array, 
    // if it isn't it'll return -1 otherwise it'll return the position of the element.
    if(keys.indexOf(value.title) > -1)
    {
       arr[value.title].push(value); // Add value to the existing array
    }
    else
    {
        arr[value.title] = [value]; // Create a new entry in the object with element wrapped as an array.
    }

}
```

A simple check using `.indexOf` will determine if the key is in the array or not. If key is in the array, push to that array otherwise create a new array with the object in it.

```js
var arr = {
  Blues: [{title:"Blues", color:"red" },{title:"Blues",color:"white" },{title:"Blues",color:"white" }],
  Jazz:  [{title:"Jazz", color:"orange"},{title:"Jazz",color:"pink"}],
  Rock:  [{title:"Rock", color:"yellow"},{title:"Rock", color:"yellow"}]
};

function addOrCreate(value)
{

    var keys = Object.keys(arr);

    if(keys.indexOf(value.title) > -1)
    {
       arr[value.title].push(value);
    }
    else
    {
    arr[value.title] = [value];
    }

}

addOrCreate({ title: "Rock", color: "black" });
console.log(arr);
addOrCreate({ title: "123", color: "black" });
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: whoa thats it thanks so much mate!, sorry if i do mistake on my explanation im new to javascript specially working with array coz what i do so far is getting the raw arrays then concat it with the new object then will group again , coz im having hard time on inserting the new object to the grouped array, thanks mate!! you save me time

Comment: can you edit the code you posted and do put some comment with a bit explaination if you dont mind ? hehe @Adriani6

Comment: @herotozero No problem. I've added comments to the first snippet. Enjoy.